# Class methods which create new instances

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, class-method, initializer

Apart from the standard `[[MyClass alloc] init]` pattern, some objects are built from static methods like `MyClass *obj = [MyClass classWithString:@"blabla"]`

According to widespread memory management guides (including Apple's), you're only responsible for releasing the objects that you `alloc`.

Can anyone provide me with a template for such methods? How do you return the allocated object (`[self alloc]; return self;`, perhaps)? How do you make sure that it will be released?

Comment: Not only `+alloc` — any method whose name starts with `alloc`, `new`, `copy`, `mutableCopy`, as well as `-retain`.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

They are class methods, not static methods<sup>1</sup>. This specific type, creating autoreleased objects, can be referred to as "factory methods" (formerly also "convenience constructors"), and they are discussed in [the **Concepts in ObjC Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassFactoryMethods/ClassFactoryMethods.html). They go something like this:

```
+ (instancetype)whatsisWithThingummy: (Thingummy *)theThingummy {
    return [[self alloc] initWithThingummy:theThingummy];
}
```

<sub>Where `Whatsis` is your class, and `Thingummy` is another class which your class uses.</sub>

If you're not compiling with ARC, the convention is to `autorelease` the instance before returning it.

The [`instancetype` keyword](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#related-result-types) was introduced by Clang for these kinds of methods; combined with `self` (which is the [class object](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch04.html#_the_secret_life_of_classes) itself<sup>2</sup> in a class method) it allows correct subclass behavior: the method produces an instance of the class which received the message.<sup>3</sup> `instancetype` allows the compiler to do more strict typechecking than `id`.

An illustration of this usage in subclasses from the framework: `+[NSString stringWithFormat:]` returns an `NSString` instance, whereas `+[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:]`, returns an instance of the subclass `NSMutableString`, without `NSMutableString` being required to explicitly override the method.

As discussed by the [**Fundamentals**][1] doc, there are other uses for these factory methods, such as accessing a singleton, or appraisal of the necessary memory allocation before it's performed (possible, but less *convenient*, with a standard `alloc`/`init` pair).

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>"Static methods" in Java or C++, ["class methods"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ClassMethod.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH8-SW1) in Objective-C. [There's no such thing as static methods in ObjC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8089623/)</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup>Whereas in an instance method `self` is, sensibly, a reference to the instance.</sub>

<sub><sup>3</sup>Previously, [like the usual initialization methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html) (`initWith...`),  you would have used `id` as the return type. Using a specific class name unnecessarily forces subclasses to override the method.</sub>

Comment: +1 for `id` as the return type, +1 for the document reference, +1 for class methods, +1 for convenience constructors.

Comment: @Bavarious: Thanks. I'm glad you didn't take away a point for poor metasyntactic variables. :)

Comment: +1 for the footnote mention of Clang's `instancetype` extension.

Comment: +1, even though I had to restrain myself from editing your metasyntactic variables.

Comment: @Josh: 'Previously, like the usual initialization methods (initWith...), you would have used id as the return type'. Is id still used as the return type with the instance methods of the style -initWith, when not incorporated as part of a class method?

Comment: @shinnyWhack: `instancetpye` [is implicit for an `init...` method](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#related-result-types), so you can use either `id` or `instancetype`.

Answer (score 4):

The objects returned from factory methods should be autoreleased, meaning they'll be cleaned up when the associated autorelease pool is drained. This means that you don't own the returned objects unless you `copy` or `retain` them. Following is an example of a factory method:

```
+ (id)myClassWithString:(NSString *)string {
    return [[[MyClass alloc] initWithString:string] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: Does using `autorelease` apply when using ARC?

Comment: @SAFX, No it doesn't, you can check this notes made by apple: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 2):

These methods are simply returning an autoreleased version of the object.

```
+(MyClass*)class
{
  MyClass* object = [[MyClass alloc] init];
  return [object autorelease];
}
```

Comment: Because of inheritance, factory methods usually have `id` as the return type.

Answer (score 1):

The modern way to do this with ARC and the latest complier is:

```
+ (instancetype) myClassWithString:(NSString *)string {
     return [[MyClass alloc] initWithString:string];
}
```

- No need to autorelease with ARC.
- [`instancetype`](http://nshipster.com/instancetype/) provides better compile time checks whilst making subclassing possible.

Comment: Is it not *better* to rename the method to begin with the word 'new' or use the NS_RETURNS_RETAINED attribute macro?

As I understand it, doing this tells ARC that it receives a +1 object that the caller should assume ownership of. It's not required though, since the default autoreleased implementation will arrive at the same result.