# Why do some objects not need to be initialized before use in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-design-patterns

Why do some objects not need to be initialized before use in objective-c?
For example why is this `NSDate *today = [NSDate date];` legal?

Comment: See also this recent question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987969/objective-c-self-allocating-objects/5988016

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are initialized within the `date` method. This is a common way to create autoreleased objects in Objective-C. Allocators of that form are called convenience allocators.

To learn more about that, read the "Factory Methods" paragraph in Apple's Cocoa Core Competencies document about Object Creation: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ObjectCreation.html

To create convenience allocator for you own classes, implement a class method, named after your class (without prefix). e.g.:

```
@implementation MYThing
...

+ (id)thing
{
  return [[[MYThing alloc] init] autorelease];
}

...
@end
```

Comment: Basically you can find convenience allocators by looking at the method name and the '+' sign in the method declaration. The name often is the class name without prefix, and the plus sign tells you that it is a class method. Apple provides them for a lot of their classes. Some prominent examples:[NSString stringWithFormat:], [NSNumber numberWithInt:], ...

Comment: The convention is that methods whose names do not begin with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy” return autoreleased objects

Comment: A small nitpick: they are "convenience _constructors_" not "allocators". See ["Combining Allocation and Initialization"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAllocInit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH22-SW12), and my recent answer to: ["Self allocating objects"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987969/objective-c-self-allocating-objects/5988016).

Comment: I read the term "convenience allocator" in "Cocoa Programming" by Anguish et. al. http://books.google.com/books?id=AeyX8GqdzPYC&pg=PA153&dq=%22convenience+allocator%22&hl=en&ei=o3PNTZ29PIiF-wbIq92QDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22convenience%20allocator%22&f=false. But "convenience constructor" makes sense of course.

Comment: The only reason, I believe, that "constructor" is more correct is that such a method doesn't _necessarily_ allocate memory, as in the case of a singleton. Like I said, though, it's just a small nit, and only based on "this is what Apple says".

Answer (score 1):

`today` *is* initialized (and autoreleased) inside the static date call.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to called an `init…` method on objects you have allocated by calling `alloc`. `alloc` only reserves space needed for the object, creating a an *unitialized* object.

An *uninitialized* object have all instance variables set to zero, nil, or equivalent for the type. Except for the retain count that is set to 1.

All other methods that return an object are guaranteed to return a fully initialized object. `alloc` is the exception.

You **must never** call an `init…` method on an object that is already initialized. Simple rule on thumb is to use a 1-to-1 relation between `alloc`-`init…`, thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Two parts.

First, as others have mentioned, a method can initialise and then autorelease an object before returning it. That's *part* of what's happening here.

The other part is how it's defined. Note how most Objective C definitions begin with a `-`? The one you mention does not. The signature looks like this:

```
+ (NSDate*) date;
```

That is, it's a *class* method and applies to the class as a whole rather than to an instance of that class.