# Potential leak of an object warning -- clarification needed

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-management, memory-leaks

After I Analyzed my code, Xcode indicated a potential leak as shown below.
[image: Screenshot of code with analysis results]

Is this something I should be concerned about?

In this code, the class that sets `doublyLinkedList` is the sole owner and continues to manage this object throughout program execution.

Comment: Down below in the `dealloc`, i have [`[self doublyLinkedList] release]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wish to do this instead:

```
if (self) {
    DoublyLinkedList *dll = [DoublyLinkedList new];
    self.doublyLinkedList = dll;
    [dll release];
}
```

In the header, declare doublyLinkedList a `@property` that is retained.

Comment: What if you assign `[self setDoublyLinkedList:[DoublyLinkedList new]];` How would you release it then? It should it be `[self setDoublyLinkedList:[[DoublyLinkedList new]] autorelease];` in this case?

Comment: Yes, autorelease there.  But make sure the @property for doublyLinkedList is set to retain.

Comment: Always write your code for best readability.  If doing it `[self setDoublyLinkedList:[[DoublyLinkedList new]] autorelease];`is best for you, then so be it.  I like to break things up so they can be easily checked by the next programmer, or if I wanted help on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you're getting the warning is because the `new` call returns a retained object, and then your setter is probably doing another `retain` on it (depends on whether it's synthesized or manually generated).

Also, I would recommend you use the standard `alloc`/`init` instead of `new`, so that the two-phase creation is obvious.

This is better:

```
if (self) {
    DoublyLinkedList *dll = [[[DoublyLinkedList alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.doublyLinkedList = dll;
}
```

or just

```
if (self) {
    self.doublyLinkedList = [[[DoublyLinkedList alloc] init] autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a "potential leak" because the Analyzer sees that you have allocated memory for a `DoublyLinkedList` instance (using `new`), put it into a local variable called `dll`, and not released that memory in the same scope.

Assuming that the `doublyLinkedList` member that you're setting happens to also be a property declared as `retain`ing, you also have an *actual* leak, because you have over-retained the `DoublyLinkedList` that you create here.

The [ownership rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH27-SW3) say that you have one claim on this instance because you called `new` to create it. When you pass the instance to `setDoublyLinkedList:`, it is retained, and you then have two claims. When the `init` method ends, you only have one reference to the instance, through the ivar/property -- you've lost the local variable -- which means that you have more ownership claims than you have references. This is a good indication that you will have a leak.

To fix the leak, you need to relinquish one of your claims before the end of the `init` method. You can do this in one of two ways, using `release` as soon as the property is set:

```
DoublyLinkedList * dll = [DoublyLinkedList new];
[self setDoublyLinkedList:dll];
[dll release];
```

or `autorelease`:

```
[self setDoublyLinkedList:[[DoublyLinkedList new] autorelease]];
// Or equivalent procedures involving a temp variable
```

However, it should be noted that using setters in `init` [may be problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192721/why-shouldnt-i-use-objective-c-2-0-accessors-in-init-dealloc) (see also [Mike Ash's writeup on the topic](http://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-11-27-using-accessors-in-init-and-dealloc.html)), because accessors can -- potentially -- have side effects that depend on your object already being fully set up. There seem to be two camps on this issue, and it's probably best to read about it and come to your own conclusions, but you may find that it simplifies your initializer methods to assign to ivars rather than using properties:

```
if( self ){
    doublyLinkedList = [DoublyLinkedList new];
}
```

This is completely correct in terms of memory management.

Finally, if `DoublyLinkedList` is a class whose code you have, you can also consider writing a convenience constructor, which will return a new, autoreleased instance for you. The convention in Cocoa is to simply name the method after the class, with standard method name casing, like so:

```
+ (id) doublyLinkedList {
    return [[[self alloc] init] autorelease];
}
```

Note that this is a class method:

```
if( self ){
    [self setDoublyLinkedList:[DoublyLinkedList doublyLinkedList]];
}
```

and see [my answer to "Self-allocating objects"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987969/objective-c-self-allocating-objects/5988016#5988016) for an explanation of these constructors.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a property called "doublyLinkedList" (assumption based on code given), and it is "retained," you can do the following:

```
if (self) {
    DoublyLinkedList *dll = [[DoublyLinkedList alloc] init]
    self.doublyLinkedList = dll;
    [dll release];
}
```