# Access NSArray from another class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IOS: call a method in another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688495/ios-call-a-method-in-another-class)

How can i pass an `NSArray` object to another class ? I don't want to use `extern` to access it, so is there any other way i could accomplish this  ?

Also note, i am a beginner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example `tableDataSource` is a `NSArray` that can be accessed as a property of a class.

In your `interface` declaration (`iPadTableWithDetailsViewController.h`):

```
@interface iPadTableWithDetailsViewController : UIViewController {
    NSArray *tableDataSource;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *tableDataSource;
```

Then, in your `implementation` definition (`iPadTableWithDetailsViewController.m`):

```
#import "iPadTableWithDetailsViewController.h"

@implementation iPadTableWithDetailsViewController

@synthesize tableDataSource;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
        self.tableDataSource = nil;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    if (!tableDataSource) {
        self.tableDataSource = [NSArray array];
    }
}

.....

@end
```

And then you can access this from another class like this:

```
- (void)doSomething {
    iPadTableWithDetailsViewController *myViewController = [[iPadTableWithDetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"iPadTableWithDetailsViewController" bundle:nil];
    myViewController.tableDataSource = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"object1", @"object2", nil];
    NSLog(@"myViewController.tableDataSource: %@", [myViewController.tableDataSource description];
}
```

More good info and examples:

[Properties in Objective-C](http://cocoacast.com/?q=node/103)
[Tutorial: Using Properties in Objective-C](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2712/using-properties-in-objective-c-tutorial)
[cocoadevcentral learn objective-c](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/)

Comment: What does this method do `- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil ` ?

Comment: It initializes a custom subclass of a `UIViewController`.  I suggest you create a template project in Xcode and read through the comments and examples, there is a lot of good info there.