# dismissViewControllerAnimated calling method in another view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to iOS Programming and now i have a problem.

There is a login screen that use `[self presentViewController:loginview animated:YES completion:nil];` to show it out in MasterViewController.

And now i want to call a method (reload data) after `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]`

this is my code:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^ {
   [self getPostData];                 // Reload Data
   [self.tableView reloadData];        // Reload Data
}];
```

but it is not working.

(the reload method is in the MasterViewController)

Anyone can help me?

Comment: What's `self`? Should it be the same object in your completionhandler?

Comment: @Larme the method is in the MasterViewController.

Comment: There are two ways, 1. Use `NSNotificationCenter` to notify a message to MasterViewController to call the above method defined in MasterViewController only. 2. Use `Protocol`

Comment: @iphonic sorry but can you say clearer about how to use `NSNotificationCenter`? Thanks

Comment: Do you wants to call method of one class from another class??

Comment: @MohitPopat yes thats what i want to do

Comment: @Arefly try iphonic's answer. its good answer

Comment: @Arefly checkout this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688495/ios-call-a-method-in-another-class

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `NSNotificationCenter` for your problem.

Define a NSNotification in your `MasterViewController` **viewDidLoad** like below

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(closeModal:) name:@"CloseModal" object:nil];
```

And then define the method as below

```
-(void)closeModal:(NSNotification *)notification{
    UIViewController *controller=(UIViewController *)notification.object;

    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^ {
         [self getPostData];                 // Reload Data
         [self.tableView reloadData];        // Reload Data
    }];

}
```

And at last from your other controller from where you are actually trying to dismiss your controller use code below

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"CloseModal" object:self];
```

Comment: i've try the code but it do not have any change to the APP (it still not reload the data)

Comment: but are you sure it is the only way? i hope there are some easiler ways and this one looks like a trick not a proper way :p

Comment: No this is one way, but as I said you can use `Protocols` too, or you can create a parent controller property in your other controller and pass MasterViewController reference and dismiss by calling a function in Master.

Comment: um... seems more difficult for me XD i will just use your solution. THX!

Answer (score 1):

what you should do is basically call method on presenting view controller as below

```
[(MasterViewController*)self.presentingViewController reloadData];
```

Comment: but it says No visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector 'reloadData'

Answer (score 0):

You can call the presentingViewController's methods which updates the Presenting view.

for example: I have a modal view which can be launched from multiple Views. And all the presenting views have the view reloading code within view will appear.

Add the below code before dissmissing the modal view.

```
        [self.presentingViewController viewWillAppear:YES];
```

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];