# Declaration of constructor which allocates and initializes itself in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, default-constructor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Class methods which create new instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987969/class-methods-which-create-new-instances)

How would you declare a constructor in objective-c which would allow you to skip the `[[class alloc] init]` step during a declaration; Instead of saying for example `Fraction* somefrac=[[Fraction alloc] init];`, just say `Fraction* somefrac` and the constructor would do the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would instantiate the object and return it. Following naming conventions you would need to make it an `autorelease`'d object that gets returned.

```
+ (id)fraction
{
    return [[[self alloc] init] autorelease];
}
```

To use it

```
Fraction *fraction = [Fraction fraction];
```

this follows the same pattern as the apple provided classes e.g.

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray array];
```

Comment: Indeed. Deleted my redundant (and lesser) answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
+(Fraction *) fraction
{
    return [[[Fraction alloc] init] autorelease];
}
```

and then you can use

```
Fraction *frac = [Fraction fraction];
```

This style is used a lot in objective c

Comment: What happens if you want to subclass `Fraction`?

Comment: @Paul.s: then you have to provide such a class method yourself. its not logical to call `[Derived base]` but rather `[Derived derived]`

Comment: That doesn't sounds very DRY to me. As you would then be writing the same method again?

Comment: @Paul.s: I know its a bit tedious, but I rather get derived object through derived function rather than base function. if anything, it would help if objective c would allow some kind of `@synthesize` syntax for converting `init`s to this.

Comment: Indeed it would. One suggestion to keep it a little DRY'er. Define it as I have in my answer then at least you could have `- (id)derived; { return [self fraction]; }` then you get all the normal benefits of changes bubbling up the inheritance tree