# How can I use a constructor class method in a subclass?

Tags: objective-c, class, inheritance, constructor, class-method

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Class methods which create new instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987969/class-methods-which-create-new-instances)

I feel like I'm missing something important.  I'm creating a matrix class for matrix algebra as an abstract superclass, with different possibilities for entries in that matrix as its subclasses.  My superclass is called `Matrix`, and my subclass is called `FractionMatrix`, where the entries are `Fraction` objects.  So I have this convenience constructor:

```
+ (Matrix *)matrix { // creates an empty matrix object
    return [[Matrix alloc] init];
}
```

If in my code I do `[FractionMatrix matrix]`, I would get a `Matrix` object rather than a `FractionMatrix` object.  Is there some way of writing this method so that I don't need to override it in the subclass -- a `self` for classes, essentially?

While in this very simple case it's not a lot of work to simply override the method, there are more substantial methods for which overriding would represent pointless code duplication.

Comment: That *definitely* answers my question; thank you!