# The use of [[self alloc] init] when writing factory methods

Tags: objective-c, class, inheritance, factory-method

I'm having trouble understanding the use of `[[self alloc] init]`  when writing factory methods. I understand that factory methods are convenience methods to create instances of a class, and that they do the `alloc`, `init`, and `autorelease` for you. I can see how this is formed, for example in the declaration of an `NSArray` property with the factory method `arrayWithArray:`, or `array`, etc. called on it to set it up. 
I can obviously see how this is different to an outright (explicit) call to `alloc` and `init`.

My issue with this is that I don't understand factory methods at a deeper level. I came across an explanation online that said instead of calling `alloc` and `init` explicitly, a class factory method could be used to basically encapsulate something like this:

```
+(instancetype)createWithString:(NSString *)string
{
    return [[self alloc] initWithString:string];
}
```

But how do `instancetype` and `[self alloc]` effectively allow for subclasses to make use of the class factory method?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. Does [Class methods which create new instances](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5987969) explain anything for you?

Comment: this approach has no issues with subclasses because `self` if resolved dynamically at runtime and will "point" to the "active class". `NSArray`, `NSNumber`, `NSString` are special cases called class clusters ([official doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html))

Comment: @Josh: Yep, that is really helpful. I'm just done reading this page and found it very useful: http://qualitycoding.org/factory-method/

Comment: Just one question. Say you do an explicit alloc - when using ARC, do you need to worry about autorelease anymore?

Comment: I meant manual release..sorry

Comment: @shinnyWhack: Nope, not necessary to call `autorelease` when using ARC. (ARC will insert that call for you.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `instancetype` is a keyword that says "the return type of this method is the type of the class that this method was called on" (or a subclass). So, if you call `[Baseclass createWithString:]`, the return type is `Baseclass *`. However, let's say you create a subclass that does *not* override this method. If you call `[Subclass createWithString:]`, the return type is `Subclass *` (not `Baseclass *`).
2. When a class receives a message, `self` points to the `Class` object. So when calling `[Baseclass createWithString:]`, `self` will point to the `Baseclass` object. However, when calling `[Subclass createWithString:`], `self` will point to `Subclass` instead, so if `Subclass` defines its own `alloc` or `initWithString:` methods (that is, it overrides them) its versions will be called instead.